# Install Windows 8 from USB but keep Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: windows-8, installation, operating-systems

I wish to install Windows 8 on my laptop. Currently, I have Windows 7 and [Ubuntu 12.10](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_12.10_Quantal_Quetzal#Ubuntu_12.10_.28Quantal_Quetzal.29) (Quantal Quetzal) available when I boot my computer up. Is there a way for me to install Windows 8 using a USB flash drive (16 GB) as opposed to a disc and in addition to Windows 7 as well as Ubuntu, at the very least keeping Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Sure there is. First from within Ubuntu or from a LiveCD [install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GParted) and run [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net). Use it to shrink existing partitions and create a new partition for Windows 8.

Next use the [Windows 7 USB/DVD download tool](http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msstore/html/pbPage.Help_Win7_usbdvd_dwnTool) (also available [here](http://wudt.codeplex.com), works fine with Win8) to transfer Windows setup to your USB stick from the ISO (if you have a DVD, you can create an ISO using something like [ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com)). Alternately you can create the Windows setup USB directly from the DVD using [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/), [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/), [WiNToBootic](http://www.wintobootic.com) or [similar tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_to_create_Live_USB_systems). Boot from the USB and install Win8 into the empty partition created for it.

Finally you'll need to [restore](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System) Ubuntu's Grub 2 boot loader (which would have been overwritten by Win8's graphical boot loader, which obviously can only recognise Win7 and not Ubuntu). This can be accomplished easily enough by running [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). Once this is done you'll be able to boot into any of the 3 OSes.